# How to separate an enumerated list into a string python

Tags: python, string, list, split

I was wondering if it were possible to split a string that is enumerated into a list. Here is what I have:

```
"1 hello 2 goodbye 3 fun 4 etc"
```

and wanted to convert it to this:

```
["1 hello", "2 goodbye", "3 fun", "4 etc"]
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More robust variant with `regex` and `list comprehension`.
Using regex `(\d+\D+)` with `re.findall()` can split enumerated strings with more than one word.

`List comprehension` is used for spaces striping.

```
import re 

x = '1 hello world 2 goodbye 3 fun 4 etc'

y = [c.strip() for c in re.findall(r"(\d+\D+)", x)]

print(y)
```

The output is

```
['1 hello world', '2 goodbye', '3 fun', '4 etc']
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Mario Ishac Answer, In case you have 2 words between 2 numbers, you can use `regex` to split on numbers:

```
import re
x = "1 hello world 2 goodbye 3 fun 4 etc"
x = re.split(r'(\d+)', x)[1:]
c = list(map("".join, zip(x[::2], x[1::2])))
print(c) # ['1 hello world ', '2 goodbye ', '3 fun ', '4 etc']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
it = iter(s.split())  
li = [a + ' ' + b for a,b in zip(it, it)]
```

or

```
it = iter(s.split())  
li = list(map(' '.join, zip(it, it)))
```

or

```
li = list(map(' '.join, zip(*(2 * [iter(s.split())] )) ))
```

zip normally extracts elements from iterators and pack them in tuples by element order, so first tuple contains all first elements, second tuple contains all second elements and so on. But in this case zip gets the same iterator twice, so for each iteration the are two extractions from the same iterator, which yields not elements number i, i but i, i+1 This is a particular case of the "grouper" recipe which you can find here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Comment: Given the surprising behaviour of zipping an iterator with itself, it would be very helpful to give an explanation for how this code works

Comment: zip normally extracts elements from iterators and pack them in tuples by element order, so first tuple contains all first elements, second tuple contains all second elements and so on. 

But in this case zip gets the same iterator twice, so for each iteration the are two extractions from the same iterator, which yields not elements number i, i but i, i+1

This is a particular case of the "grouper" recipe which you can find here: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools-recipes]

Comment: @angeldeluz777 update your answer with your explanation that you wrote in comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list comprehension`:

```
In [516]: x = "1 hello 2 goodbye 3 fun 4 etc"    
In [517]: x = x.split(' ')

In [519]: [" ".join(x[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(x), 2)]    
Out[519]: ['1 hello', '2 goodbye', '3 fun', '4 etc']
```

OR using `regex`:

```
In [520]: import re    
In [521]: x = "1 hello 2 goodbye 3 fun 4 etc" 

In [523]: re.findall("[^ ]+ [^ ]+", x)
Out[523]: ['1 hello', '2 goodbye', '3 fun', '4 etc']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `zip`:

```
a = "1 hello 2 goodbye 3 fun 4 etc"
a = a.split()

numbers = a[::2]
words = a[1::2]

b = [number + " " + word for number, word in zip(numbers, words)]
```

`b` ends up being `['1 hello', '2 goodbye', '3 fun', '4 etc']`

You can also assign `b` as such:

```
b = map(" ".join, zip(numbers, words))
```

In this case, `b` is an iterator (and the join operation is lazily applied). `list(b)` would be `['1 hello', '2 goodbye', '3 fun', '4 etc']`.